# Ignite org.h2.message.DbException: Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters:

Tags: java, ignite

We have upgraded ignite 2.7.6 to 2.11.1 server. But getting below exception while querying the database:

```
[2023-01-18T04:56:14,637][ERROR][client-connector-#143][JdbcRequestHandler] Failed to execute SQL query [reqId=29, req=JdbcQueryExecuteRequest [schemaName=PUBLIC, pageSize=1024, maxRows=0, sqlQry=SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID IN (?), args=Object[] [1], stmtType=SELECT_STATEMENT_TYPE, autoCommit=true, partResReq=false, explicitTimeout=false, super=JdbcRequest [type=2, reqId=29]]]
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: General error: "class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Runtime failure on lookup row: IndexSearchRowImpl [rowHnd=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.index.QueryIndexRowHandler@5b289c8e]"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID IN (?) [50000-197]
.
.
.
.
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: General error: "class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Runtime failure on lookup row: IndexSearchRowImpl [rowHnd=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.index.QueryIndexRowHandler@5b289c8e]"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID IN (?) [50000-197]
.
.
.
.
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Runtime failure on lookup row: IndexSearchRowImpl [rowHnd=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.index.QueryIndexRowHandler@5b289c8e]"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID IN (?) [50000-197]
.
.
.
.
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Runtime failure on lookup row: IndexSearchRowImpl [rowHnd=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.index.QueryIndexRowHandler@5b289c8e]
.
.
.
.
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Rows cannot be compared
.
.
.
.
Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters: "1" [90003-197]
```

Any help/suggestion would really appreciated.